# Cannot save images using Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, 22.04

When I <kbd>right-click</kbd> on an image and select *Save as*, the dialog opens as usual. I then choose the location I want to save the file to, the file's name and click *Save*. No error message, but no file saved to system.

Anyone else get this? Is it an Ubuntu, a snap, or a Firefox issue?

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall firefox using apt not snap

Answer (score 9):

The solution is here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701403

> ```
> sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
> ```

Comment: This is the answer, thankyou

Comment: worked for me too, thanks, man

Comment: Worked for me too.
Why is this not installed as a requirements for firefox?

Comment: Using the metapackage ``xdg-desktop-portal`` automatically selects the most appropriate desktop variant version.  E.g., I needed ``xdg-desktop-portal-kde`` instead of what is in the current version of the answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is a known File Chooser bug which you can find here: [Clicking the "Save" button doesn't actually download the file](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/4907)

The bug is unrelated to Firefox being a snap application and also exists on other browsers (Brave, Chrome, etc.), as well as other programs that use the File Chooser. The issue happens not only on image files but for any type of files.

A workaround for this issue until it gets fixed is to not click the *Save* button, but instead press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard after navigating to the location you want to save your file to,  as [mentioned in a comment](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/4907#note_1450269) in the above bug report.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the broader information about the issue. Unfortunately the work-about does not work `pressing enter and not clicking on the save button`

Comment: did not work for me(((

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround: If you have the URL of the photo, you can use `curl`, `cd` to the folder where you want to save your photo, and then run:

```
curl '<url>' -o <save_as>
```

where `<url>` is the URL of the photo (notice that it should be within quotes) and `<save_as>` is the file name you want to save the photo as.

Example:

```
curl 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/RedcrestedTuraco.jpg/1280px-RedcrestedTuraco.jpg' -o a_bird.jpg
```

Comment: I don't seem to find any other way to save photos using firefox, the above solution didn't work for me.