# Upload File Button does not work

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Chrome Version:  108.0.5359.124
Firefox Version: 108.0.1
Edge Version: 109.0.1518.26

Somewhere in the last month or so I have noticed that my Ubuntu 22.04 PC no longer responds to the File Upload button (System File Dialog does not popup) in Firefox or Chrome.  It started in Chrome first and then right before Christmas I noticed it happening in Firefox.  Today I installed Edge with the same results.

I have tested with multiple websites and still no response. Searching for a fix has not yet been successful.  All of the stated possible answers do not seem to work.

Looking for any kind of suggestions.

To better explain the problem I am facing, if you visit w3schools website https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_file_upload_button, on my PC clicking on the `Choose File` button does nothing.  It does not matter which browser I used none of them will respond when clicking on the `Choose File` button.

Is this a browser issue, or a Ubuntu issue?  I have ran across a few sites that state some files could be missing but everything I try does not work.

Additionally I have noticed that the export bookmarks does not work on any web browser as well.

Thanks

Comment: Rebooted computer today and the problem is back...  Something else must be going on. Is this a bug?

Comment: Have you tried it on other browsers?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this problem was related to this [Cannot save images using Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410902/cannot-save-images-using-firefox-on-ubuntu-22-04/1449632#1449632)
Because in my case this [Firefox snap in Jammy cannot save at all...](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701403) solved both problems.

Just instaling XDG:
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gtk